# Spring Security SAML: How to configure redirect URL after successful logout

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0

The Spring Security SAML module, when configured with:

```
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            //other stuff...
            .saml2Logout(withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
```

will redirect to *localhost:port/login?logout* by default, and it's also stated in the documentation that it can *"Redirect to any configured successful logout endpoint"*, but I can't seem to find where or how to configure this redirect URL.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/logout.html

I've checked the 5 customizable components demonstrated in the doc (Logout request & response resolutions, authentication and storage) but none of them seems to cover the redirect URL.

Another not-so-elegant approach I thought is to apply a filter externally to redirect any request to "/login?logout" to my desired redirect location, but it's definitely not the proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [this issue on spring-security's GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12111#issuecomment-1297239583):

> By default, saml2logout() inherits from the logout(). So you can do:
>
> ```java
>     http
>         .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/myLogoutSuccessUrl")
>         .saml2Logout(Customizer.withDefaults())
> ```

Using the code you provided, this would look like this:

```java
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            //other stuff...
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/myLogoutSuccessUrl")
            .saml2Logout(withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
```